# before and after pointers, doubly linked list in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, insertion, doubly-linked-list

Is anyone familiar with before* and after* pointers when using a doubly linked list with two dummy nodes in c++? I am trying to account for all the special cases of insertions (empty list, insert at very front, insert at very back, insert in the middle) using a before* and after* as my iterators.

How do you correctly use the before* and after* to determine where to insert?

Any feedback is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try drawing it out on paper.

Comment: You obviously wouldn't want to add one before/after the head/tail, I doubt that's what you meant. Inserting a new node between the head/tail and the first/last element is fine, if not a good idea. [`std::list`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/) provides push/pop_front/back.

Answer (score 2):

With two dummy nodes, there are no special cases. Since you always have a dummy node in front and a dummy node at the end, you *never* operate on an empty list. You *never* insert at the very front. You never *insert* at the very back. All insertions and deletions are in the middle -- that's the point of the two sentinel nodes.

Comment: So, all insertions should be possible with just one iterator and the given head and tail? The way you explain that there are no special cases makes much more sense than the use of all the additional pointers. Thank you!

Comment: You store the head and tail so you can walk the chain. But for an insertion, you just need the insertion point. It will never be at the beginning, since you can't insert before the head dummy node, and it will never be at the end since you can't insert after the tail dummy node. It makes things nice and clean ... no special cases.